# Apache Server Error The specified network name is no longer available. : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, tomcat

We are facing the following issue on our apache server:

[Sun Apr 14 10:33:26 2013] [warn] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed

This error seems to have occurred out of nowhere and for no apparent reason. It's causing the server to be extremely slow and is filling our report log.
We have about 1000 users on different networks all of which accessing the central server. The application is a private web application, not a website.
All of our users have windows desktops. The server uses windows server 2008, with apache server version 2.0.8 with load balancing, that distributes load on two servers.
I have already seen the following link:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21425

which actually increased my confusion. No one has come up with a definitive solution, but as far as I've seen, this may have been caused by networking issues (as a comment indicated that they have replicated the issue on IIS server). So I hop I have come to the correct place.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.